# How to bind jquery datepicker function with underlying java spring form java.util.Date fields?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying all day to bind the jQuery datepicker function with two fields of an underlying java spring form date fields of java.util.Date type but I am getting an error.
I am posting all the files and the error message.

form.jspx (jquery is loaded from a tiles default template):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
          version="2.0" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<spring:message code="city_label" var="cityLabel"/>
<spring:message code="state_label" var="stateLabel"/>
<spring:message code="arrivalDate_label" var="arrivalDateLabel"/>
<spring:message code="departureDate_label" var="departureDateLabel"/>
<spring:message code="numberOfAdults_label" var="numberOfAdultsLabel"/>
<spring:message code="submit_label" var="submitLabel"/>
    <spring:message code="select_city_label" var="selectCityLabel"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#arrivalDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeYear: true
            });
            $('#departureDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeYear: true
            });

        });
    </script>

    <h2>Enter search for hotel!</h2>
    <c:if test="${not empty message}">${message}</c:if>

<form:form modelAttribute="formdata">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>${cityLabel}</td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="city" id="cityOptions">
                    <form:option value="">${selectCityLabel}</form:option>
                    <form:option value="New York">New York</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Chicago">Chicago</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Houston">Houston</form:option>
                    <form:option value="Phoenix">Phoenix</form:option>
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${arrivalDateLabel}</td>
            <td><form:input path="arrivalDate"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${departureDateLabel}</td>
            <td><form:input path="departureDate"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${numberOfAdultsLabel}</td>
            <td><form:input path="numberOfAdults" id="adultsInput"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="${submitLabel}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

</jsp:root>
```

FormData.java :

```
package domain;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import java.util.Date;


public class FormData {

    private String stateCode;

    private String city;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yy-mm-dd")
    private Date arrivalDate;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yy-mm-dd")
    private Date departureDate;

    private Integer numberOfAdults;

    //getters and setters
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Date getArrivalDate() {
        return arrivalDate;
    }

    public void setArrivalDate(Date arrivalDate) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
    }

    public Date getDepartureDate() {
        return departureDate;
    }

    public void setDepartureDate(Date departureDate) {
        this.departureDate = departureDate;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfAdults() {
        return numberOfAdults;
    }

    public void setNumberOfAdults(Integer numberOfAdults) {
        this.numberOfAdults = numberOfAdults;
    }

    //other methods
    public String toString()
    {
        if (city.equals("New York"))
            stateCode = "NY";
        else if(city.equals("Los Angeles"))
            stateCode = "CA";
        else if(city.equals("Chicago"))
            stateCode = "IL";
        else if(city.equals("Houston"))
            stateCode = "TX";
        else if(city.equals("Phoenix"))
            stateCode = "AZ";



        return "http://api.ean.com/ean" + "-" + "services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&apiKey=97zvrux6eahgv64r3aarb7n2&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD"
                + "&city=" + city
                + "&stateProvinceCode=" + stateCode
                + "&countryCode=US&supplierCacheTolerance=MED"
                + "&arrivalDate=" + arrivalDate.toString()
                + "&departureDate=" + departureDate.toString()
                + "&room1=" + numberOfAdults
                + "&numberOfResults=1";
    }
}
```

SearchController.java :

```
package web.search.controller;

import domain.FormData;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import web.blogapp.controller.EntryController;


@RequestMapping("/search")
@Controller
public class SearchController {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntryController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadFormPage(Model uiModel) {
        logger.info("Listing blog entries");

        uiModel.addAttribute("formdata", new FormData());


        return "search/form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute FormData formdata, Model uiModel)
    {
        uiModel.addAttribute("message", "Successfully saved data: " + formdata.toString());
        return "search/form";
    }
}
```

The error I am getting after pressing submit is the following :

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'formdata' available as request attribute
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:128)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:200)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.search.form_jspx._jspService(form_jspx.java:145)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
>   org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
>   org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
>   org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(default_jspx.java:619)
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:140)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
>   org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
>   org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
>   org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:145)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
> ```

Debugging the application and stopping inside submitForm method I have the following values
stateCode :TX
city : Houston
arrivalDate : Mon Jan 21 00:07:00 EET 2013
departureDate : Wed Jan 30 00:07:00 EET 2013
numberOfAdults : 1

Comment: I also fixed an error in submitForm method (formdata object name) but the error remains the same.

Comment: Maybe it is not a date field problem after all but I am doing something wrong with the post action of the form.Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I've added some debugging information at the end of the post.I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: I solved this by using another jspx page for the POST action.