# Set Date Param in Mysql from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have jsp page view and in java and I am getting **datepicker** value in Java

Using this : `LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();`

I am not able to set this value using query in **Mysql** database where type is date in my table of column **date of birth**

Comment: I think you might first convert the LocalDate to Date. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simpliest-conversion

Comment: have another question with tags: jquery, javascript and java. This one is more related to "how to set a date field in mysql"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `PreparedStatement`, You just need to convert `LocalDate` into `sql.date` and set it in, e.g.:

```
LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();
Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
PreparedStatement pStmt = //your preparedstatement
pStmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: Also how to get datepicker from UI to Java

Comment: what is *"from UI to Java"* supposed to mean?

Comment: @specializt I think he's trying to do something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746669/how-to-bind-jquery-datepicker-function-with-underlying-java-spring-form-java-uti

Answer (score 0):

The date format for mysql insert query is YYYY-MM-DD

example:

> INSERT INTO table_name (date_column) VALUE ('YYYY-MM-DD');

so change your java code to generate such YYYY-MM-DD string

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

// ...

LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
if (date != null) {
    display.setText(formatter.format(date));
} else {
    display.setText("");
}
```

Comment: and how to recieve jquery datepicker in java

Comment: not sure, have a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746669/how-to-bind-jquery-datepicker-function-with-underlying-java-spring-form-java-uti

Comment: what is datepicker name of tag element input type date?

Comment: whatever id you have assigned to the input div element